# What do image source paths mean in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, window, icons

I'm looking at the source code for the project I'm working on in Visual Studio, and the paths look weird in the WPF window XAML. For example, the icon member of the window element looks like this: `Icon="/ProjectName;component/icons/ProjectName.ico"`

First of all, what does the semicolon mean? Does that indicate two possible paths? That doesn't make sense.

I'm guessing `ProjectName;component` represents a path, because there's no `component` folder in my project. In my project folder, `icons/ProjectName.ico` is where the icon is.

What does it all mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx), without the prefix `pack://application:,,,`, which is automatically added by the XAML Parser.

The full Pack URI would be

```
pack://application:,,,/ProjectName;component/icons/ProjectName.ico
```

and would reference a resource file named `ProjectName.ico` in an `icons` subfolder in the referenced assembly `ProjectName`. The `;component` part separates the assembly name from the file path.

If the resource file is in the local assembly, you could omit the referenced assembly part, and write

```
pack://application:,,,/icons/ProjectName.ico
```

or in XAML just

```
/icons/ProjectName.ico
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a pretty hefty MSDN page. I didn't know about Pack URI's.  Is there any compelling reason to not go with just `/icons/ProjectName.ico`?

Comment: No, you should just write the short version.

Comment: Can you speculate on why the longer version might have been used? Could it have been automatically generated?

Comment: No idea, sorry. Unless you are explicitly referencing a resource in a different assembly, the long version makes no sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

That URI means the image file is included in your project as content. "ProjectName" is your project name.

Comment: Resource, not Content. A Content File Pack URI can't have an assembly name part.